# How to detect VPN is enabled in android?

Tags: android, vpn

I am not able to check the virtual private network status in android app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is not clear.  1) What do you mean by "is enabled"?  2) What do you mean by "status"?  (It is not the same as "enabled"!)  3)  When you say you are "not able to check", do you mean that you don't how to, or that something (apart from lack of knowledge) is stopping you.

Comment: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, it is important that you are clear.  Otherwise 1) people trying to help you are likely to waste their valuable time while trying to figure out what you are actually asking, and 2) your question is unlikely to be helpful to other people with the same problem as you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isVPNConnected() {
    List<String> networkList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
            if (networkInterface.isUp()) {networkList.add(networkInterface.getName());}
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.dbg("isVPNConnected Network List exception");
    }
    return networkList.contains("tun0") || networkList.contains("ppp0");
}
```